# SCSS @Each Nesting Naming Issue

Tags: sass, each

Im looking at nesting @each loops but for the nested version i want to take a value form the parent @each, See below

```
    $team-rooms-color: (
        lightBlue: #29B0CE,
        red: #D13B3B,
        purple: #A365C9,
        darkBlue: #3B77D1,
        orange: #F19B00,
        yellow: #E2CE17,
        green: #86C61E,
        turquoise: #12D2BB
    );

    $team-rooms-color--lightBlue: (
        1: #29B0CE,
        2: #D13B3B,
        3: #A365C9,
        4: #3B77D1,
        5: #F19B00,
        6: #E2CE17,
        7: #86C61E,
        8: #12D2BB,
        9: #ff00ff,
        10: #323232
    );

    @each $name, $value in $team-rooms-color {

        // CSS Goes HERE

        @each $name, $value in $team-rooms-color--#{$name} {

            &--highlighted-#{$name} {
                background-color: $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

So what I want to do is loop through "team-rooms-color" and within there use the name to then loops through "team-rooms-color--lightBlue"

The line im looking at that doesnt seem to be working is @each $name, $value in $team-rooms-color--#{$name}